# Как в ssh узнать ip адрес, с которого установлено текущее соединение?

Tags: безопасность, ssh, vpn

После того как подключился к ssh, через какую команду можно узнать ip адрес с которого установлено текущее подключение? Т.е. мне нужно узнать, подключился ли я к ssh через VPN и скрыл свой реальный ip или трафик идет напрямую.

Answer (score 2):

согласно `man ssh` имеется такая переменная окружения:

> SSH_CONNECTION Identifies the client and server ends of the connection.  The variable contains four space-separated values: client IP address, client port number, server IP address, and server port number.

```
$ echo $SSH_CONNECTION
192.168.0.123 41412 192.168.0.1 22
```

первый `ip` — это и есть адрес клиента (с точки зрения демона `sshd`, который и добавляет эту переменную в окружение запускаемой в результате подключения программы, обычно — оболочки).

---

несложной операцией этот адрес можно отделить от остального содержимого переменной. например:

```
$ echo $SSH_CONNECTION | cut -d ' ' -f 1
192.168.0.123
```